# If user logout of app,can they still receive push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification

User login in app and logout ,can user receive push notifications? And my another question is before logout user receive push notifications and he logout and user click on push notification then what happened?

In above mentioned 2nd case I think either open app or show 1st screen or show login screen.

Comment: It depends on how are you managing it.. If you are wiping the data then user won't be able to do or see anything.. If you are not then the user will see or do what you code is written for... If you don't want the user to receive notification then check if the user is logged in then only send the notification.. For logout make an API call to let server know that the user is not logged in...

Comment: the push notification is controlled by the gcm token. if the user logs out, normally, no, they keep their gcm token since they registered already. if they delete and install again, they will receive anew gcm token and the prcess starts off.